# Ping command to test ingress traffic

Tags: linux, firewall, cisco

i have cluster and local addresses are configurated. my firewall only support ingress traffic. i want to test the following.

if any traffic coming from local address like 192.168.1.12 which can be out side the cluster  firewall than it should block it by very simple way for example ping (linux). 
Or how i can use ping to varify my firewall.

Answer (score 0):

In the firewall's CLI, assuming it's an ASA, you should be able to enter...

*packet-tracer input  icmp 192.168.1.12 8 8*

Note the "8 8" is the ICMP type and code, I use 8 8 because it's where my fingers naturally go. The command changes a little depending on what protocol, eg the TCP version is going to use source and destination ports, not codes.

If you're not sure which interface... well, the packet tracer tells you which interface your packets will leave on, so just try it a few different ways.

If you don't have CLI access, then you'll want to do a TCPing (Windows version available via Googling it, *NIX* version available in pretty much every distro's repository) to a port on your server that you KNOW is open for some, but not for the machine on which you run the TCPing from. If TCPing shows the port open, guess what... your firewall isn't working as intended.

Hope it helps!